# Hosting node js website to Azure. Default path / not working

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

I have a node js website which I am deploying to the azure server using visual studio code. The following is my code at server.js

```
var express =require('express');
var bodyParser=require("body-parser")
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/',function(req,res){

console.log('hello from server');

 res.render('./public/index.html');

  });
```

I deployed the website to an azure app service and the url always expects the index.html to be added to it to work. for e.g https://abc.azurewebsites.net does not work but https://abc.azurewebsites.net/index.html works. How do I remove the index.html from the url?

My azure folder structure is site/wwwroot/public/all html files.

Can anyone please suggest a solution

Comment: Based on window os or linux os?

Comment: Based on windows os

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

**`web.config`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.html"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Original Answer:**

Just add a file named `.htaccess` to the root directory('/site/wwwroot'), and this is the content of the file:

`DirectoryIndex public/index.html`

After that, default of your web app will change to 'public/index.html'.

Comment: Tried .htaccess not working. Do we have to set it in web.config?

Comment: @Philomath I have update the web.config. You can google 'rewrite' of web.config(And this should no need to achieve by code.).